# trying to list employees who are hired prior to 2007 and have a bonus of at least than 8.00

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is what my SQL query looks like, however my return still displays some employees that have a bonus less than 8.00, what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_HIREDATE, EMP_PCT
FROM employee
WHERE EMP_HIREDATE < #01/01/2007#
AND EMP_PCT  >=  #8.00# ;
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Why are you using #8.00#? You can just use '8.00'.

Comment: when I use '8.00' I get the message "Data Type mismatch in criteria expression"

Answer (score 3):

MS Access uses `#` for *date* literals, but not other constants.  I would strongly recommend that you use yyyy/mm/dd format for dates.  So:

```
SELECT EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_HIREDATE, EMP_PCT
FROM employee
WHERE EMP_HIREDATE < #2017/01/01# AND
      EMP_PCT  >=  8.00;
```

If `EMP_PCT` is really a value between 0 and 1, then you might want to use `0.08` instead of `8.00`.

Comment: This worked! and thank you for the clarification. I greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_HIREDATE, EMP_PCT
FROM employee
WHERE EMP_HIREDATE < '01/01/2007'
AND cast(EMP_PCT as float)  >=   8.00
```

Comment: That's not valid Access SQL, and will cause a syntax error.